# Switch tabbar programmatically and viewdidload question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I am using the set selected index method in the tabbar to switch views but I noticed that the viewdidload method gets called all the time. Is that something expected? This is odd because I would expect the xib to have already been loaded. So basically if i switch to view 1 then call view 2 and then back to view 1 , view 1 would have called viewdidload 2 times which is odd.

I would appreciate if someone can clarify that.

Comment: Nope , it is all from the xib.

Comment: I am setting the tabbar programatically.

Comment: Can you add a check to see if `viewDidUnload` is called? If this is the case then the view was unloaded to reclaim memory so it needs to be remade again by calling `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I second that. You should design your view controllers so that it can be released at any time. In other words, it is not *odd*, it is a feature.

Comment: This is not called . There's no memory warning.

Answer (score 1):

Are you retaining the view properly? To me, it seems like that would be the issue.

Comment: Well the tabbar controller is declared in the xib with all the other controllers. So my guess would be I don't need to retain them.

Comment: actually u might be right. I am going to try and add a retain prop before calling the setindex stuff.

Comment: Looks like i don't need to do that. I just added a check to make sure the view is not loaded twice.